# PHP destructor exceeds time limit

Tags: php, performance, destructor

Recently I noticed that a page from my local site exceeds time limit of 30 seconds for execution. This is caused by the destructor of the class Common, from which all DB models inherits the code. I thought that the problem is whithin the code from the function but no. The __destruct method code():

```
public function __destruct() {
    foreach(get_class_vars(get_class($this)) as $varName=>$varValue) {
        $this->$varName = null;
    }
}
```

I commented out the foreach, and no success, time limit exceeded. The I comented the method, this made the page to load as normally.

Till the time exceeding moment there were 52 calls of the method. What can be the cause of this, if the method with no code takes much time to execute?

Comment: can you create a full (small/minimal) script which reproduces the problem?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, tried to reproduce but unsuccessfully.

Comment: @SpartakusMd if you can't manage to build up a test case from scratch, go in the other direction. Delete as much code as you can from your current script while preserving the bug. Eventually, hopefully, you'll trim your script down to a minimal test case. And personally, I'm very interested to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do this. PHP will do this for you.

Comment: true && good advice. doesn't really address the actual question though.

Comment: Thought this must be said, and in this case as an answer not a comment. (Because nobody should copy this code)